Where to create HttpClient and where to call it?
I'm new to C# and I'm trying to figure things out. I need to send a request to an endpoint. I couldn't understand the C# project structure. I'm using WPF. What is the best practice to keep HttpClient? Which folder or cs file suitable for this?
Is there a resource where I can learn the project structure?

Do you have dependency injection in place? If so, it is recommended to inject HttpClient or HttpClientFactory. The Details depend on your application.

In a classic desktop App without DI and such you might simply do what the docs says and orient yourself along the example given there. The relevant comment from the example for such an app "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use." And then you might dive deeper into the docs that might help if your app is different in whatever way.

It depends on both your project architecture and preferences. I've seen plenty of approaches like:

Placing HttpClient in the assembly where you'll use it, creating a
dedicated folder beforehand. It's better to have different .cs file for every HttpClient you're going to create;
Create a different project using assembly naming conventions and
adding the suffix .API, where you can store all models, clients,
etc. related to API.

To answer your question about project structure, you can try reading Rider's article. However, I suggest not being keen on one single article but trying to find different ways to do that. For instance, there is an article from Microsoft here, where you can see the example of WPF MVVM implementation as well as the Github link.
Also, it makes sense to try using Refit to make implementation easier. I'd give it a try.
